# How do I display arbitrary text and numbers in the scoreboard sidebar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to display any kind of text/number on my scoreboard.

Answer (score 3):

The sidebar is a display of "players" and their scores in one scoreboard. You can create a scoreboard like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add scoreboard_id dummy "Scoreboard display text"
```

This creates a scoreboard with the ID "`scoreboard_id`" that is shown in the sidebar and in the feedback of some commands as "Scoreboard display text" and is of type "`dummy`", which means that nothing changes it except for commands.

To show it in the sidebar, do this:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar scoreboard_id
```

But it doesn't actually show up until someone has a score in that scoreboard.

Now to the thing you actually asked about: To show arbitrary text in the sidebar, you need to set a score of a "dummy player" to a value. Example:

```
/scoreboard players set player_name scoreboard_id 42
```

This will show up like this in the sidebar:

[image]

But be careful! There is a real Minecraft account named "[player_name](https://namemc.com/profile/Player_Name.1)" ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20200414003756/https://namemc.com/profile/Player_Name.1)), so if that person is on your server or plays a map that you release or anything like that, you will actually set their score to that value. There are only two ways I know around that:

1. Use something that can't be a real player name, like "`$name`". But it will be displayed like that on the sidebar.
2. Use the [formatting code](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Formatting_codes&oldid=1548137)) "`$r`" before the dummy player name. The problem is that this only works in functions. So you need to create a datapack with a function that does nothing except setting a scoreboard score, have it enabled and run the function instead of directly running the command.

<sub>Thanks to Lilith in the Minecraft commands Discord chat for the tip about the formatting code!</sub>